# Get value inside dynamic DIVs

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am having difficulty getting the value inside of a set of dynamically created divs using jQuery. All divs are created with PHP and there are 6 different sets of dynamic divs. My code for the divs look like the following:

```
foreach ($data as $ad) 
{
   echo "<div class='rowDiv' id='" . $ad['name'] ."'>" . $ad['name'] . "</div>";
}
```

And here is how I am trying to retrieve the values inside of the div.

```
$('.rowDiv').click(function(){
    var name = $('.rowDiv').text();
    console.log(name);
});
```

However doing this ends up with showing every single value in all the divs with the same class name. How can I specify it to retrieve the value only in the div which has been clicked?

Comment: which element has the class `movieDiv`? Should you target `$(this)` within your click handler instead?

Comment: apologies its meant to be rowDiv I changed to names of the class recently and forgot that one.

Comment: `$('.rowDiv').click(function(){ var name = $(this).text();` If you only want the text of the clicked div, use `$(this)` to specify only that div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handler basically target every elements with `.rowDiv` class in the page.

Change your code to

```
$('.rowDiv').click(function(){
  var name = $(this).text();
  console.log(name);
});
```

to target only the clicked one